# Why the table is not inserted in Model.edmx file diagram

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with SQL Server and EF6, when I created the ADO.NET data model, all my tables in the database were inserted into the `.edmx` diagram except this one table (shown below). When I opened the `.edmx` properties, I found this (MODEL.SupervisorAOI Assassination) but not (MODEL.SupervisorAOI Entity Type).

Is there any error in my table?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SupervisorAOI] 
(
    [supervisorid] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [AOIId] INT NOT NULL,
    [SUPAOI] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_SupervisorAOI_AreaOfInterest] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([AOIId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AreaOFInterest] ([AOIId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SupervisorAOI_Supervisors] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([supervisorid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Supervisors] ([supervisorId])
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `table` does not have a `Primary Key`. You may have `SUPAOI` column identity but this is not enough..

Working around `EntityFramework` need to have a `Primary Key (Entity Key)` on tables.The best practices each table should be `PK`. Change table structure and add a Primary Column then update Model..

```
 [SUPAOI] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
```

**Note:** if you do not use PK, you must provide table uniqueness , but it's not good idea..

Comment: I do this but also not display the table PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SupervisorID] ASC, [AreaOIID] ASC),

Answer (score 1):

The problem I could see is that your primary key needs not to have 'not null' as primary keys are not nullable by default. Make it look like the following.

```
[SUPAOID] INT IDENTITY
```

It is also advisable to name your primary key as ID or append the primary key with Id. Your primary key could be  SUPAOID or SupervisorAOIID.